# How to post form content to a card component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I was hoping someone could explain to me how I can get the information submitted in my form to show up in a card component? In a way it's a glorified todo list, but I want to know what best practice would be (ie grabbing the data from my database or from the store...?)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { saveItem } from '../actions/index';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class AddItem extends React.Component {
 
 render() {
  console.log(this.props);
  return(

 <form onSubmit={(event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const input = {
   name: event.target.itemName.value,
   price: event.target.itemPrice.value,
   description: event.target.itemDescription.value, 
   userEmail: this.props.currentUser.email
  }

  this.props.dispatch(saveItem(input))
  
  event.target.itemName.value = ''
  event.target.itemPrice.value = ''
  event.target.itemDescription.value = ''
 }}>
    <label>
     Item Name:
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="itemName" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
     Price:
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="itemPrice" />
    </label>
    <br />
    
    <br />
    <label>
    Description:
     <br />
     <textarea type="text" name="itemDescription"/>
    </label>
    <br />
    <button>Submit</button>
   </form>
  )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentUser: state.auth.currentUser
});
 
 export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AddItem));
```

so basically I need all of this info to show up in a container when the user hits submit.

Answer (score 0):

These two options have pros and cons, the main differences are:

Using Redux Store:

- Refreshing the page will erase all the data stored in your store
- The data is in the client, means better performance
- Harder to maintain as your apps grows -> store gets nested/larger.

Using Database:

- the data is persisted and can be fetched whenever you want
- fetching data takes a while and requires an endpoint + server call
- much more organized

In general, use your store for temporary data, while your DB for persisting vital data.
In practice, you will find yourself using these methods interchangeably or even both simultaneously. e.g saving a copy of the data in the store before POSTing it into your DB, so the data will be still available for you to display it.

Last tip: https://hackernoon.com/shape-your-redux-store-like-your-database-98faa4754fd5